# How to fix : Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in chalk/ansi-regex

Tags: node.js, linux, security, npm, npm-install

sudo npm audit gives me this error -

## npm audit report

ansi-regex  >2.1.1 <5.0.1

Severity: moderate

Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in chalk/ansi-regex - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-93q8-gq69-wqmw

fix available via `npm audit fix`

node_modules/npm/node_modules/cli-table3/node_modules/ansi-regex

node_modules/npm/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/ansi-regex

strip-ansi  4.0.0 - 5.2.0

Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-regex

node_modules/npm/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/strip-ansi

```
string-width  2.1.0 - 4.1.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
node_modules/npm/node_modules/string-width
```

3 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix

**I have also tried

> sudo npm audit fix

and the result I've got is quite same.**

npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@5.0.0 node_modules/npm
/node_modules/cli-table3/node_modules/ansi-regex

npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@5.0.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@5.0.0 npm@8.4.1 at node_modules/npm

npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@5.0.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.

npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@5.0.0 Check for updates to the npm package.

npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 node_modules/npm/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/ansi-regex

npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 is a bundled dependency of

npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 npm@8.4.1 at node_modules/npm

npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.

npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 Check for updates to the npm package.

npm WARN audit fix strip-ansi@4.0.0 node_modules/npm/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/strip-ansi

npm WARN audit fix strip-ansi@4.0.0 is a bundled dependency of

npm WARN audit fix strip-ansi@4.0.0 npm@8.4.1 at node_modules/npm

npm WARN audit fix strip-ansi@4.0.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.

npm WARN audit fix strip-ansi@4.0.0 Check for updates to the npm package.

npm WARN audit fix string-width@2.1.1 node_modules/npm/node_modules/string-width

npm WARN audit fix string-width@2.1.1 is a bundled dependency of

npm WARN audit fix string-width@2.1.1 npm@8.4.1 at node_modules/npm

npm WARN audit fix string-width@2.1.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.

npm WARN audit fix string-width@2.1.1 Check for updates to the npm package.

up to date, audited 317 packages in 3s

28 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

## npm audit report

ansi-regex  >2.1.1 <5.0.1

Severity: moderate

Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in chalk/ansi-regex - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-93q8-gq69-wqmw

fix available via `npm audit fix`

node_modules/npm/node_modules/cli-table3/node_modules/ansi-regex

node_modules/npm/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/ansi-regex

strip-ansi  4.0.0 - 5.2.0

Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-regex

node_modules/npm/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/strip-ansi

```
string-width  2.1.0 - 4.1.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
node_modules/npm/node_modules/string-width
```

3 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:

npm audit fix

Comment: What is your question? The output already contains "fix available via npm audit fix" and "To address all issues, run: npm audit fix". Does that not work? Or have you not read the error message?

Comment: "fix available via npm audit fix" does not work !!!

Comment: Why not? What does it do? Define "not work". It should update your package.json file with new versions of the libs. If it's a transitive dependency, then you have to wait for the direct dependency to release a fixed version, I guess (or replace it with a different ilbrary). I don't see anywhere in the question that `npm audit fix` was run and its output

Comment: I have run npm audit fix with sudo npm audit fix .

Answer (score 1):

So this warning means that you need to be using a patched version of that package (from that GH link, it looks like all x.0.1 are patched). So if you have a package that uses `ansi-regex` and that packages isn't updated to a patched version, you could open a pull request to that package updating it